# Vuejs Display a router name in Component

Tags: vue.js

How can I display a router name in a component ?
Example:

```
const routes = [
{ path: '/documents', component: Documents, name:"Documents"  ,props:true},
{ path: '/queries', component: Queries, name:"Queries", props:true}
]
```

I want to display the **name** property as a title in the component. Is this possible? how?

Comment: `this.$route.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props:true` will convert path parameters to properties:

```
{ path: '/documents/:name', component: Documents, name:"Documents", props:true},
```

You can use an object instead of `true` and then send in a string.

```
{ path: '/documents', component: Documents, name:"Documents", props:{ name:'Documents'}},
```

In your component, register the property

```
props: { name:String }
```

And then use it in a template like this:

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

You can also refer to the route name using the components $route object

```
<div>{{$route.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify title to a component you can use router's meta property, [Link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914)

```
const routes = [
{ 
  path: '/documents', 
  component: Documents,
  name:"Documents" ,
  props:true,
  meta: {
    title: 'Documents'
  }
},
{ 
  path: '/queries',
  component: Queries,
  name:"Queries",
  props:true,
  meta: {
    title: 'Queries'
  }
 }
]
```

In main.js,

```
import router from '@/routes'
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = `Currently at - ${to.meta.title}`
  next()
})
```